# Today's departure or Today departure

Tags: possessives, attributive-nouns

I write this phrase every day in my emails and every time it bothers me which way is correct.

"Please assist with today departure". (or today's departure).
"Cargo will leave on today flight". (or today's flight).

Answer (score 4):

**Today** is not a determiner (like "please assist with *my* departure"), or usually used as an adjective (like "please assist with *heavy* items") or so you can't use it that way: **today's flight/departure** is the only idiomatic way.

Yes, you can sometimes use a noun as a modifier (like "please provide *chicken* soup") but **today** is not idiomatically used that way.

Comment: +1 According to CGEL, _Today_ is actually a pronoun! It belongs to this group because 1. It is interpreted deictically; 2. It cannot take a determiner (cf. the ungrammatical *_The today_); and 3. It has a genitive form (_Today's_ as in _Today's departure_).

Answer (score 0):

You should use today's because it refers to the object.